# html форматирование в string

Tags: android, html, sqlite, разметка, форматирование

Добрый вечер всем! У меня создана база данных. В разметке textview и туда я вынимаю из БД. В string ячейка содержит, например:

```
 <![CDATA[
   <h2>Стих </h2>
    У лукоморья дуб <font color="green">зеленый</font>;<br>
    Златая цепь на дубе том: <br>
    И днём и ночью <b>кот учёный</b> <br>
    Всё ходит по цепи кругом; <br>
    Идёт <b>направо</b> - песнь заводит, <br>
    <img src="header" /><br/><br/>
    <b>Налево</b> - сказку говорит. <br>
    Златая цепь на дубе том: <br>
    И днём и ночью <b>кот учёный</b> <br>
    <img src="file:///android_asset/header3.jpg"><br/><br/>
```

В MainActivity

```
  TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
    tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.txt)));
```

Но вместо картинок эти квадратики. Что сделать, чтобы фото были? Естественно картинки я поместил в assets. Пробовал и с drawable. И будут ли они работать, если учесть что это БД SQLite? Спасибо.

Comment: Они вроде и не должны загружается.  почитайте про ImageGetter

Answer (score 1):

Писал не проверял ну суть ясна думаю

```
    public class ActivityOne extends Activity implements ImageGetter{

    TextView new;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.help_menu);
        String code = "текст: <img src = 'ссылка' > текст.</p></td>";

        new = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.new);       
        Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml(code, this, null);
        new.setText(spanned);

    }

    @Override
    public Drawable getDrawable(String arg) {


        LevelListDrawable d = new LevelListDrawable();
Drawable empty = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        d.addLevel(0, 0, empty);
        d.setBounds(0, 0, empty.getIntrinsicWidth(), empty.getIntrinsicHeight());


       Glide.with(this).load(arg).into(d);



            return d;
        }

    }
```

Если не хочешь использовать Glide есть примеры https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16179285